# Best way to hide/show depending on select options with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with two options in it. I'd like the default option to have an input displayed below the select element, while the other option, when selected, hides that input and instead displays a paragraph of text. I've tried using bind and change but I can't manage to get it to work. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please show your non-working code to get accurate help.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear and got two good answers. Just because it doesn't make any sense to one person doesn't make it an illegitimate request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
​<select id="foo">
    <option value="1">Enter a value</option>
    <option value="2">Show some text</option>
</select>

<input id="input" type="text"/>

<p id="text" style="display:none">
    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
</p>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

```
​$('#foo').change(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.val() === "1") {
        $('#input').show();
        $('#text').hide();            
    } else {
        $('#text').show();
        $('#input').hide();
    }      
});​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J5Enp/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tiny, reusable function that reduces some code clutter with show/hide.

```
jQuery.fn.showIf = function (condition) {
return this[condition ? 'show' : 'hide']();
}
```

You use it like this:

```
$('#foo').change(function() {
    $('#input').showIf(el.val() === "1");
    $('#text').showIf(el.val() !== "1");
});
```

Comment: toggle? :) http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Comment: this was Todd Menier's code. Can't credit on the site like I would have wanted to.